# Swift Generics - Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics, realm, rx-swift, objectmapper

I am trying to develop a generic API fetch method but I am getting above compilation error. After several hours of trying I am still not able to fix it.

**Type Alias**

```
typealias RealmResponse<T> = (Int, Results<T>?, ErrorResponse?) where T:Object, T:Mappable
```

**Class Declaration**

```
class Profile:Object, Mappable{
}
```

**API Fetch Method**

```
@discardableResult
func requestRealmObject<T>(endPoint:String,
                           disposeBag:DisposeBag,
                           method:HTTPMethod = .get,
                           query:[String:Any] = [:],
                           params:[String:Any] = [:]) -> Observable<RealmResponse<T>> where T:Object, T:Mappable{

    let realmResponse:Observable<ObjectResponse<T>> = APIManager.requestObject(endpoint: endPoint,
                                                                               method: method,
                                                                               query: query,
                                                                               params: params)
        .shareReplay(1)

    realmResponse
        .filter{ 200..<300 ~= $0.0 }
        .map{ response:ObjectResponse<Profile> -> [Profile] in
            if let profile = response.1{
                return [profile]
            }
            return []
        }
        .subscribe(APIManager.shared.realm.rx.add(update: true, onError: nil))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    let realmObjects = APIManager.shared.realm.objects(T.self)
    return Observable.zip(realmResponse, Observable.collection(from: realmObjects)){ (response, results) in
        return (response.0, results, response.2)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let profileObserver:Observable<RealmResponse<Profile>> = requestRealmObject(endpoint: APIManager.userProfileEndPoint,
                            disposeBag:disposeBag,
                            method: .post,
                            query:[:],
                            params:["username":loggedInUser.value])
        .shareReplay(1)
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't right code like `$0.1 != nil ? [$0.1!] : []`. nobody knows  what's going on.

Comment: Give meaningful names in places where it's not obvious what's happening: `map { something in something.optionalElement.map { element in return [element] } ?? [] }`

Comment: Here is expanded map operator: `.map{ response:ObjectResponse<Profile> -> [Profile] in
                if let profile = response.1{
                    return [profile]
                }
                return []
            }` ObjectResponse is another alias `typealias ObjectResponse<T> = (Int, T?, ErrorResponse?)`